# Minimalistic flatfile-based "wall" PHP app with authentication and RSS?

Tags: php, rss, open-source, forum, flatfile

I am looking for an open-source minimalistic "message board" PHP software.
Not a forum, more something like one simple facebook wall.
The only thing a user can do is post a new message.

With RSS, and able to run on flat files (no database) with Apache+PHP
Authentication based on a configuration file, no management UI needed.

For now I use this software, but it lacks RSS:
http://nrw.free.fr/data/projects/pano/demo/index.php?pano=ifc

Anyone knows a software that matches my description?
Thanks!

*Usage: communication between my family's 5 members living on different continents.*

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is called *guestbook* (minus the authentication part). Check Internet, there are plenty of these. If you know PHP you can write your own in 5 mins.

Comment: Indeed, a guestbook plus authentication, exactly! I wrote an open-source software like this in PHP in 2003. While it is not complicated, archiving is not totally trivial, and adding RSS would take some time, I would prefer an existing software that has a community using it.

Comment: There are free RSS generators... and what do you mean by "archiving" - paging of some sort? I'm sorry I can't point you to exact application, my opinion is still that you can write a better application given with that level of simplicity :)

Comment: Yes, by "archiving" I mean paging, so that all thousands of messages do not show up, just the most recent ones. If such an open-source application already exist, I would obviously rather use it than maintain my custom one.